# javascript ajax doesn't work after caching

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

javascript ajax calls fails with offline caching in HTML5. I've already tested without caching the HTML5 application and it worked fine. any idea with regards to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

javascript snippet:

```
 function getData(){
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                  alert(this.responseText);
                }else if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status !== 200){
                  alert("alert");
                }
         }     
         xmlhttp.open("GET", serviceURL , true);
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json', 'text/javascript');
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', 'charset=utf-8');
         xmlhttp.send('');
       }
```

Comment: It's a `GET` request, it's supposed to be cached. Can you show us the cache manifest file?

Comment: if you are really need it to be always not cached, you can force it by passing a parameter with some random/unique string or UUID on it. for example : http://myserver.com/test?key=randomUUIDhere

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've figured out the problem, which "NETWORK" is not included in the manifest by mistake as the service being public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is in your manifest file.

but if this tag is not there then please include

```
NETWORK:
# Do Not Cache these Files
*
```

**if this is not there then your ajax call will be fail.**

Comment: Thanks. This was the part I missed.